# Redirect stdout with pipes and fork in C

Tags: c, pipe

I have an exercise about ptrace and pipes. The following code is a part from whole program.
Pipes are made before main part and this_trace.s_out is 1. Main father create child and this child makes his own child for stdout. When program runs ls then it is print on screen and doesn't write in file. What is wrong?

```
if(pid == 0)
{
char buf0[BUFFSIZE], buf1[BUFFSIZE], buf2[BUFFSIZE];
int length0, length1, length2;


if(this_trace.s_out == 1)   //For stdout redirection
{
    if((pid1=fork()) == -1)
    {
        perror("fork");
        exit(1); 
    }

    if(pid1 == 0) //child for stdout redirect
    {//sleep(2);
        if(fd1 = open(this_trace.out_name,O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0666) == -1)
        {
            perror("create stdout file");
            exit(1);
        }


        close(p_out[WRITE]);
        close(p_in[READ]);
        close(p_in[WRITE]);
        close(p_err[READ]);
        close(p_err[WRITE]);

        do{
            if((length1 = read(p_out[READ],buf1,BUFFSIZE)) == -1)
            {
                perror("Read for stdout redirection");
                exit(1);
            }
            write(fd1, buf1, length1);
        }while(length1 > 0);


        close(fd1);
        //close(p_out[READ]);
        return 0;
        //break;

    }
    else if(pid1 > 0)//child from main father
    {
        close(p_out[READ]);
        close(p_in[READ]);
        close(p_in[WRITE]);
        close(p_err[READ]);
        close(p_err[WRITE]);

        dup2(p_out[WRITE], 1);
    }

}




ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, 0, NULL, NULL);  


//execv(argv[1],NULL);
execl("/bin/ls","ls",NULL);


}
```

Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear why you have so many processes.  You have a problem at:

```
if (fd1 = open(this_trace.out_name,O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0666) == -1)
```

This assigns 0 or 1 to `fd1`, regardless of the file descriptor opened.  It should be:

```
if ((fd1 = open(this_trace.out_name,O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0666)) == -1)
```

After you use `dup2()` (or `dup()`) to redirect a file descriptor to a standard channel, you should close the original file descriptor.  Thus, after `dup2(p_out[WRITE], 1);` you need `close(p_out[WRITE]);`.

You should detect failure from `execl()` and deal with it; if the `execl()` returns, it failed.

You show unused variables `buf0` and `buf2` (and corresponding `length0` and `length2`).

Comment: Thank you. After a lot of time some things are difficult to see them. Some of variables are for other redirection. The reason for so many processes is the professor who give us the exercise

Comment: I have just done your changes and everything works fine.

Thank you again

Comment: For stdin I did this but the program never end without ctrl-c
do
{
 if((length0 = read(fd0,buf0,BUFFSIZE)) == -1)
 {
  perror("Read for stdin redirection");
  exit(1);
 }
 write(p_in[WRITE], buf0, length0);
}while(length0 > 0);

Comment: Well, you should avoid `do ... while (...)` loops whenever possible.  I'd certainly want to write: `while ((length0 = read(fd0, buf0, sizeof(buf0))) > 0) write(p_in[WRITE], buf0, length0);` possibly checking that the `write()` was successful.  Without your complete program, though, I can only guess what you're up to.  The primary thing you need to do is ensure that all processes close all the stray ends of all the pipes.  Very often, a never-ending loop like this is because some process in the list has the other end of the input pipe open for writing (that might be the current process).